# Generating Random Number with Certain Rate

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

I have the following C++ code that tried to generate
a random number. The [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601727/generating-synthetic-dna-sequence-with-subtitution-rate/601750#601750) is we given some rate "x" and number of runs;
we hope it would generate the number as many as (x * number of runs times).

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>       
#include <time.h>        
using namespace std;     


int main  () {

    // Initialize Random Seed 
    srand (time(NULL));

    string line;
    double SubsRate = 0.003;  
    double nofRuns   = 1000000;

    for (unsigned i=0; i < nofRuns ; i++) {

        int toSub = rand() % 1000 + 1;

        if (toSub == (SubsRate * 1000)) {
         cout << toSub << " Sub"  << endl; 
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hence if we run the code above K times with this command:

```
$ a=0 ; while test $a -lt 10 ; do ./MyCode | wc -l ; a=`expr $a + 1` ; done
```

We expect it to generate number "3" as many as ~3000 times in 1M runs. But 
some how my code above my code above only generate number "3" as many as 900 ~ 1000 times.

How can I improve on my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you are checking that the result == 3, not that the result is <= 3.

3 will only happen, one in 1000 times, but <= 3 will happen at the rate you want.

Answer (score 2):

- You will expect to get number 3 one time out of 1000, i.e. 1000 times out of 1M.
- You will expect to get number 9 one time out of 1000, i.e. 1000 times out of 1M.
- You will expect to get number 7 one time out of 1000, i.e. 1000 times out of 1M.
- You will expect to get either one of 3, 7 or 9 three times out of 1000, i.e. 3000 times out of 1M.

Answer (score 1):

I think your math here is a little off...

According to the code you have up there, you will uniformly be generating random numbers between 1 and 1000.

Your check (toSub==(SubsRate*1000)) merely checks if the number you have generated is 3 (since rate*1000=3). Hence, you will only get 3 once about 1000 times, not 3000 times.

You didn't mention what the range for your numbers are, but generally speaking, if you want to generate a number in a range between IMIN and IMAX using a uniform distribution (each value has the same chance of appearing), then you simply write:

```
int I = IMin + rand() % (IMax - IMin);
```

In this case, if you wanted each number to appear once every 3000 times, you would have to randomize a number between 1 and 3000. Otherwise, you are not talking about a uniform distribution.

Comment: As noted in the answer to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614012/howto-restart-loop-in-c-finding-unique-sequence-over-random-runs/614029#614029 it is not very good to use the above formula to get uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your original was testing whether the random number is equal to the fraction of the distribution you wanted, not below that.

`rand()` generates a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX` (inclusive). `RAND_MAX` may be quite small - a typical value is 32767. If you use modulo 1000, then there are 32 values which `rand()` returns which map to each value from 768 to 999, and 33 values which map to values 0 to 767. So that's a little skewed.

You seem to have pulled 1000 out the air. If instead you scale `RAND_MAX` itself by the proportion of the distribution you want, then you don't get the skewing effect, nor do you have to process the output of rand() to make the comparison:

```
int main  () {
    srand (time(NULL));

    double subsRate = 0.003;  

    unsigned int nofRuns   = 1000000;

    int cutoff = (int) ( subsRate * ( (long) RAND_MAX + 1L ) );

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nofRuns ; i++) 
        if ( rand() < cutoff ) 
            cout << " Sub "  << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```